Connection refused after OAuth2 consent in Google Docs API
I am using the quickstart Go script from this page. I have followed all the steps there and I've got my credentials.json. When I'm in the Google login page to give the OAuth consent and I click "Continue", it redirects me to http://localhost/?state=state-token&code=PROBABLY_SECRET_CODE&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly and I get a connection refused error.
I don't understand what is causing this error because I have followed all the steps. I obviously do not have any authorization code which the script is asking me, so I cannot continue.
Can anyone reproduce this issue? How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

I solved it!
It turns out that the code that the script is asking me for IS the actual secret code in the URL. All I needed was to take the part after &code= and paste it in the terminal and it worked.
The documentation doesn't explain this, so I assumed it getting an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED wasn't supposed to happen (and maybe it isn't?). Google should update that page!
